# How to use check_prototype_definition in CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I am looking at the documentation of check_prototype_definition here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckPrototypeDefinition.html

```
check_prototype_definition(FUNCTION PROTOTYPE RETURN HEADER VARIABLE)

FUNCTION - The name of the function (used to check if prototype exists)
PROTOTYPE- The prototype to check.
RETURN - The return value of the function.
HEADER - The header files required.
VARIABLE - The variable to store the result.
           Will be created as an internal cache variable.
```

I don't understand what RETURN value of the function means, I am not passing parameters to the function I am checking the prototype, is this the value to store in named VARIABLE ?

I see a function name, a prototype (which I guess includes the function) and a header... Is the exact prototype string matched and found inside the header?

I can't seem to find much information online on how to use this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `CheckPrototypeDefinition.cmake`, the check works by implementing a function with a `PROTOTYPE` signature. Literally. That is, CMake creates a source file with, say

```
struct passwd *getpwent_r(struct passwd *src, char *buf, int buflen)
{
     ???
}
```

And to make it compile, it also has to put something instead of `???`. This part is filled with

```
return RETURN;
```

So, you can provide any valid value that matches the return value of the signature you're checking for: `0` for `int`, `"blabla"` for `char*` and so on.

Comment: I feel like this moves me closer to understand the mechanism but I still am not quite sure on the usecase for this. Is it to check an attribute is correctly defined in a header? I am failing at grasping which problems this is meant to solve. :/

Comment: @eri0o "this" - the `RETURN` keyword? You simply can't use `check_prototype_definition` without providing a correct `RETURN` value.

Comment: @eri0o If you're talking about `check_prototype_definition`, then it is used when you want to check not only function's existence, but also its signature. For instance, some non-POSIX C functions have different number of arguments on Linux and FreeBSD.